# How to create persistent volumes using OpenShift API

Tags: openshift

I am building an OpenShift client that is using [OpenShift's REST API](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/rest_api/index.html) to perform various operations on the cluster. I would like to have this client create a **persistent volume**. The default developer user cannot create persistent volumes but the administrator can. I am trying to find the best way to create a persistent volume in a default OpenShift origin  deployment without requiring user input and using only the REST APIs, without any `oc` usage.

I see two possible solutions:

- Create the persistent volume as the user *admin*. However, I cannot figure out how to use the APIs as an *admin* since this user account has no token. I have tried to examine `oc` logs but cannot reverse engineer how it can authenticate as an admin.
- Add the permission to create persistent volumes to the user *developer*. I would like to avoid this but if it comes to that I am willing to take this solution into consideration. Anybody knows what kind of permission the developer user needs to be able to create a persistent volume?

How to create a persistent volume using only the OpenShift API?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user or service account for persistent volume manipulation.

The roles that would need are cluster roles, and there's already one existing role called "**system:persistent-volume-provisioner**"

```
$ oc get clusterrole/system:persistent-volume-provisioner -o yaml --as system:admin
apiVersion: authorization.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    authorization.openshift.io/system-only: "true"
    openshift.io/reconcile-protect: "false"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-03-16T13:18:45Z
  name: system:persistent-volume-provisioner
  resourceVersion: "134"
  selfLink: /apis/authorization.openshift.io/v1/clusterroles/system%3Apersistent-volume-provisioner
  uid: 8e253e28-291c-11e8-b0f7-36c91e93ae8e
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - persistentvolumes
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - update
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - storage.k8s.io
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - storageclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - list
  - patch
  - update
  - watch
```

If this cluster role has more than what you need, just create one with less permissions.